# Magento .htaccess error in Godaddy shared hosting

Tags: magento

I have installed Magento in Godaddy shared hosting with apache mod_rewrite enabled while installing magento. The installation completed and homepage loaded quite good. But when I try to access any other pages it gives me "500 Internal Server Error" in every page when I access with www.myshop.com/admin or www.myshop.com/sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc.html.

However, when I access www.myshop.com/index.php/admin and www.myshop.com/index.php/sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc.html is works just fine.

Godaddy support buys told me they've enabled apache mod_rewrite in shared hosting as well. They suggest me there's some misconfiguration in .htaccess. Can anyone help me. I'm posting the .htaccess here.

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    RewriteBase /home/content/33/7605133/html/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Comment: look to the apache or php error log to get the real error behind this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is this line
RewriteBase /home/content/33/7605133/html/

Look at the comment above that line
"you can put here your magento root folder
path relative to web root"

So it needs to be relative to the webroot so if your webroot is /home/content/33/7605133/html/
Which I think it would be then you need to change that line to

RewriteBase /

Answer (score 1):

I just finished a magento installation on a godaddy virtualhost and ran up with the same problem.

The fix was to do the following:

1. In godaddy host administration panel adjust the php version to match that of your magento installation(in my case magento 1.9.1.0 CE -community edition), I've changed it to 5.4.
2. Then on your .htaccess file of your magento's base directory change the rewrite base directive to point to the relative path like this:

   RewriteBase /
3. On this same file, add at the end of it the following: 
   RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ [L]
4. Add the following directives to the php5.ini file at the root of your godaddy's virtualhost(if it doesn't exist create one with the same exact name specified):

   [sourcecode language="php"]
   register_globals = on
   allow_url_fopen = on
   cgi.fix_pathinfo =1
   [/sourcecode]
5. And that's it(don't forget to save all file changes and close the files used.

For a full explanation and more detailed steps go to the following article.
[The article](http://linngoneblog.blogspot.mx/2015/04/magento-godaddy-virtualhost.html)